# getting a value into my textarea

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following to set the value of a text area..

```
 <?php
 $description=$myrow["description"];
 ?>


 <textarea name="description" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?>" readonly></textarea>
```

but it doesn’t appear to be working. The value of message is not null. Does anyone have any idea why it's not filling the value?

Comment: `textarea` value should be between opening and closing tags. `input` values use the _value_ attribute since they do not have an innerHTML content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<textarea>` does not have `value` attribute like `<input type="text" value="InputValue"/>`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

[From W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html)

Do like this:

```
<textarea name="description" readonly><?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put textarea value like this:

```
<?php
  $description=$myrow["description"];
?>


 <textarea name="description" readonly><?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?></textarea>  <!--passing the value between opening and closing textarea tags.-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
 $description=$myrow["description"];
?>


 <textarea name="description" readonly><?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
<textarea name="description"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?></textarea>
```

> **textarea** value not defined using value property like value ="value" you need to do like `<textarea> value </textarea>`